# Did the Multicore Association go out of business?

Tags: multicore

I am working on a project with the ADSP-SC58x from Analog Devices which uses Multicore Communications API (MCAPI). As I am trying to gain more information about the API and standardization itself I recognized that the website from the Multicore Association (https://www.multicore-association.org) is down. Does anyone have an idea if they went out of business?

I tried to obtain some files and documentation with the waybackmachine (https://archive.org/web/web.php) but that did not work out.

Comment: Did you try their social media? They have presences on Facebook and LinkedIn...

Comment: Thx for the hint. I checked their twitter account, but the last post was from 2013 or so. Unfortunately I do not have Facebook or LinkedIn. I tried to mail them directly.

Comment: Good luck https://web.archive.org/web/20160930200119/https://www.youtube.com/user/multiassoc more https://web.archive.org/web/20190712161150/https://www.multicore-association.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view they go out of business as their registered trademarks have the status canceled.

See following references from WIPO Global Brand Database:

- [MTAPI](https://www3.wipo.int/branddb/en/showData.jsp?ID=USTM.85409910)
- [MRAPI](https://www3.wipo.int/branddb/en/showData.jsp?ID=USTM.85409915)
- [MCAPI](https://www3.wipo.int/branddb/en/showData.jsp?ID=USTM.85409918)